# check external links invalid in a web site

Tags: php

i wrote a script on php in order to check external links invalid in a web site 
this is the sript

```
<?php 
 // It may take a whils to spider a website ... 
 set_time_limit(10000); 

 // Inculde the phpcrawl-mainclass 
 include_once('../PHPCrawl_083/PHPCrawl_083/libs/PHPCrawler.class.php'); 
  include ('check.php');  
 // Extend the class and override the handleDocumentInfo()-method 
  class MyCrawler extends PHPCrawler 

  {   
   function handleDocumentInfo(PHPCrawlerDocumentInfo $DocInfo) { 
   if (PHP_SAPI == "cli") $lb = "\n"; 
   else {
   $lb = "<br />"; 
     // Print the URL and the HTTP-status-Code 
     // Print the refering URL 
      $file = file_get_contents($DocInfo->url);
      preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href="([^"]+)/i', $file, $urls);
     echo '<br/>';
     $home_url = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
    foreach($urls as $url){
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($url);$i++){
    $link_url = parse_url( $url[$i] );
     if( $link_url['host'] != $home_url['host'] ) { 
            if (check_url($url[$i])=== false){
    echo " Page requested:  ".$DocInfo->url." (".$DocInfo->http_status_code.")".$lb; 
         echo '<br/>';
       echo "<font color=green >"."lien externe invalide :".$url[$i].$lb."    </font>";
         echo '<br/>';
                    }
                 }
               }
             }
          }
       }
     }
     $crawler = new MyCrawler(); 
     $crawler->setURL("http://www.tunisie-web.org "); 

    $crawler->addURLFilterRule("#\.(jpg|gif|png|pdf|jpeg|css|js)$# i"); 
    $crawler->setWorkingDirectory("C:/Users/mayss/Documents/travailcrawl/"); 
     $crawler->go(); 
    ?>
```

but more than external links(not invalid :/) it gives      "http://www.tunisie-web.org" as an axternal link and i don't know where is the problem !! 
please help 
and this is check.php :

```
    <?php 
    function check_url($url) {
   if ( !filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL,FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED) === false)  {
      return true ;
      }
     else {
      return false;
      }
    }
    ?>
```